# example of chinese remainder theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

The chinese remainder theorem says that if I consider $\mathbb{Z}/{6\mathbb{Z}}$ I can write it as $\mathbb{Z}/{2\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{Z}/{3\mathbb{Z}}$ since $(2,3)=1$. If $\alpha$ goes a system of representatives mod $6$  does $\alpha$ also go a system mod $3$ ?

Comment: Could you reword the second sentence? I'm not sure what you are saying. CRT only says that there is a isomorphism between $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that, when $\alpha$ goes through a system of representatives  of congruence classes modulo $6$, the pairs $(\alpha\bmod 2,\alpha\bmod 3)$ go through the set of all pairs of (representatives of) congruence classes mod $2$ and mod $3$.